# Executable server started from .bat script needs input to continue executing?

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I've written a small batch file to start an executable located in the same directory with some environment variables.

The executable itself is a Node server packaged with [pkg](https://github.com/vercel/pkg), and it runs fine, but it seems like the program only runs and continues to log to stdout if I'm pressing keys while the terminal is in focus. If logs are streaming quickly and there's not much delay between logs, then the program seems to run fine, but otherwise if there's any idle time then it seems to need input to continue executing.

I have this file:

```
@echo off
SET PORT=3004
SET NODE_ENV=development
SET ENV=development
START /d ".\" main.exe
```

...and double click the `start_program.bat` which opens a terminal window where the server starts fine, but won't respond to HTTP requests until I press a key. Any kind of HTTP request just stalls until I press a key in the terminal window, then the request continues like nothing's wrong.

Not sure if I'm doing something strange in this file, or if there are more parameters I need for `START`, but I'm pretty new to running code on Windows, so any direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: There is no need to use `START` to run `main.exe` - just invoke it directly, and to make sure that you reference it in the same directory as the batch file itself, use `"%~dp0main.exe"`

Comment: The problem is most likely with trying to use `START`, and not for the reason mentioned in the previous comment, but because you've also named your script `start` too. **Please rename your script to a name which is not also the name of another command.**

Comment: Edited to clarify that the name of my bat file isn't actually start.bat, apologies that was an example. Behavior still occurs regardless of file name.

Answer (score 0):

try to run main.exe with command

```
echo.|main.exe
```